# Как сделать проверку на права админстратора на Pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, бот, pyrogram

Делаю админ бота на Pyrogram, мне нужно сделать способ проверки прав администратора в моем случаи `can_restrict_members`
Как правильно написать запрос?

https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/ChatMember#chatmember
https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/ChatPrivileges#pyrogram.types.ChatPrivileges

Код который я попытался сделать выглядит иным образом: `if app.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id).status == 'creator' or app.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id).can_restrict_members:`

Comment: Выполните 
member = await app.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
print(member)

что выведет?

Comment: По идее он должен вернуть объект ChatMember у которого есть privilegies. Вот в privilegies и должен храниться can_restrict_members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправьте

`app.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id).can_restrict_members`

на

`app.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id).privileges.can_restrict_members`

(вернёт True/False)

Если нужно узнать, владелец ли группы, то вот такое выражение

`(member.status == member.status.OWNER)`

(так же вернёт True/False)